# .get() in jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery

i have a problem with the jQuery method .get(). In previously codes, i was having this:

```
$('.quote_button').click(function(){  

    var enlace = $('a', this).attr('href');
    $.get(enlace, function(replyPost){

        var QuoteContent = $(replyPost).find('.editor').html();
        $('textarea[name=message]').val($('textarea[name=message]').val() + QuoteContent);
    });

});
```

This works perfect. But in a new code, i don't get i want it. This:

```
$('#linkFile').click(function(){

    var linkFL = "http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=sy9gt3FR";

    $.get(linkFL, function(data){

        var onLine = $(data).find('.embedFooter a:nth-child(3)').text();
        alert(onLine); //onLine is undefined
    });
});
```

I don't understand because, i tested add to local.html the element of '.embedFooter' from linkFL.html, and worked perfect (onLine = "See original"). But calling $.get() don't (onLine = undefined).

Any idea? :(

EDIT: code with embed code (works) and calling .get() (doen't wors).

http://jsfiddle.net/u4BXs/

Comment: `.get()` in jQuery *does* work

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)!!!!

Comment: It looks like previously you might be loading the resource from same origin now you are loading resource from a different domain causing [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) Violation

Comment: Yes, the first code load from same page, and the second code is a external page. So, is not possible do i want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment, you can't do cross-domain AJAX query,

if you want to resolve this, you can use [JSONP](http://json-p.org/):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=sy9gt3FR",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function (data) {
     // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but inside the function(data) to get '.embedFooter a:nth-child(3)' for example, what i should code?

Comment: @Madh, sorry but JSONP only work for JSON object (your link return text/html mime type).
The best way to solve your issue is to use a [web-proxy](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html).